# Is it possible to explicitly tell if a node is using Geth or Parity?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, infura, rpc, ethers.js

Is it possible to explicitly tell if a node is using Geth or Parity?

This can be from a raw RPC call or the Infura (or other provider) layer. Is there an explicit way to do this without making an arbitrary call and looking for the `trace` methods (for example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of call to tell whether you are running Nethermind or Geth :)

admin.nodeInfo
web3.clientVersion

[image]

Comment: Awesome! That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.